# user input to create pie chart using reactjs from form

Tags: reactjs

how to create chart taking input from the user from a form in reactjs

I made a form and pie chart not getting an idea of how to access data from a form

```
chartData:{
        datasets:[{
              data:[10,20,30,40,50]
                  }]
           }
```

i want the chart to be created by the inputs form the form

Comment: which liberary you are using for chart

Comment: react-chartjs-2

Comment: I had added the code use it will work for you

Answer (score 1):

> Use the following code will generate a dynamic chart

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {  Pie } from "react-chartjs-2";


export default class App extends Component {
    state = {
        dataPie: {
            datasets: [{
                data: [10, 20, 30]
            }],

        },
        first: "",
        second: "",
    }
    handleSubmit = () => {
        const { dataPie } = this.state;
        this.setState({
            dataPie: {
                ...dataPie,
                datasets: [{
                    ...dataPie.datasets,
                    data: [
                    this.state.first,
                     this.state.second
                       ]
                }]
            }
        })
    }
    handleChange = (evt) => {
        let a = parseInt(evt.target.value)
        this.setState({
            [evt.target.name]: a,
        })
    }
    render() {


        const { data, dataPie } = this.state;
        console.log(dataPie);
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                <input type="number"
                    value={this.state.first}
                    name="first"
                    onChange={(evt) => this.handleChange(evt)} />
                <input type="number"
                    value={this.state.second}
                    name="second" onChange={(evt) => this.handleChange(evt)} />
                <button onClick={() => this.handleSubmit()}>add data to chart</button>
                <h1>pie chart</h1>
                <Pie data={dataPie} />
            </React.Fragment>

        )
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't want a static value. In this  (data:[10,20,30,40,50],) i want the value which i enter through input fields

Comment: @Divya I have added the code that dynamically update the chart using inputs

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Please keep on guiding us

Comment: if this code help you then please accept it as answer

Comment: but if i want the whole chart should be only 100% . i have taken 5 input fields bt i dont want the total chart to exceed 100

Comment: actually it does not exceed 100 % becuase if give the numbers it automatically mange the values

Comment: if I have 5 input fields .in total of all 5 fields the maxvalue=100 a total of 5 fields should not be more than 100. if it exceeds I want an alert msg to show

Comment: then you should calulate the value in handleSubmit method if the values sum is greater then then return it like this `if(sum>100){ return }`

Comment: thank u but why the color is not getting applied in slices

Comment: colors are in different array you should manage them also using set state. If this answer help you accept it as answer it help other peoples as well

Comment: now I have an issue, that if I try to change the value of 1 input field the whole chart appears over the other chart.otherthan replacing the chart or just adjusting that single slice of the chart

Comment: ` data: [...dataPie.datasets[0].data,
                    this.state.first, this.state.second]
                }]` change this to ` data: [  this.state.first, this.state.second]
                }]`

Comment: Thank u so much @Sanaullah.U gave me a very big solution to my problem.Thank u once again

Answer (score 1):

```
export default class App extends Component {
    state = {
        dataPie: {
            datasets: [{
                data: [10, 20, 30]
            }],

        },
        first: "",
        second: "",
    }
    handleSubmit = () => {
        const { dataPie } = this.state;
        this.setState({
            dataPie: {
                ...dataPie,
                datasets: [{
                    ...dataPie.datasets,
                    data: [...dataPie.datasets[0].data,
                    this.state.first, this.state.second]
                }]
            }
        })
    }
    handleChange = (evt) => {
        let a = parseInt(evt.target.value)
        this.setState({
            [evt.target.name]: a,
        })
    }
    render() {


        const { data, dataPie } = this.state;
        console.log(dataPie);
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                <input type="number"
                    value={this.state.first}
                    name="first"
                    onChange={(evt) => this.handleChange(evt)} />
                <input type="number"
                    value={this.state.second}
                    name="second" onChange={(evt) => this.handleChange(evt)} />
                <button onClick={() => this.handleSubmit()}>add data to chart</button>
                <h1>pie chart</h1>
                <Pie data={dataPie} />
            </React.Fragment>

        )
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried to do polar chart using this codes it is working properly with few changes but now I want the circles in polar chart should be 10 each containing value 10. the input entered for one slice should be in one color the remaining should be of other color.eg: if my input value of 1 slice is 100 out of 10 the remaining 90 of that single slice should be of another color this should be done for my 5 inputs

Comment: I want something similar to this given link https://miro.medium.com/max/982/1*7q-Pe76n2lvvIfqWmlyiNg.jpeg

Comment: how to add two data field to a single label but one should remain default 10 and other should change according to my input given through input field

Comment: for a polar chart using reactjs

Answer (score 0):

data: [...dataPie.datasets[0].data, this.state.first, this.state.second] }]`change this to` data: [ this.state.first, this.state.second] }]